# Executing java from c++ in linux

Tags: java, c++, linux, system

I'm very new to c++ programming in linux and I want to execute java program from c++. When I do:

```
int main() {

    system("java -jar /home/user/test/test.jar argument");
    cout << "The end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

my main process waits until java is done and then continues. Is there any way I could "trigger" java without stopping my main process? Thanx in advance!

Comment: Use the JNI to create a JVM in your process.

Comment: You might be able to run it in the background via the command line `system("java -jar /home/user/test/test.jar argument  > /dev/null 2>&1 &");` I have no idea if that would work but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Tnx, I've tried, but it doesn't run the java, it just jumps to "The end" line

Comment: @KerrekSB, I haven't mentioned it, I do it on ARM7 linux and I am limited, don't know if I can try your metod, thank you for the effort :)

Comment: Forking a new process is not an option, right?

Comment: @Fildor, it is an option, I've tried with  execl(), but nothing  happend, I must have set the arguments wrong

Comment: Have you tried with `fork()` ? [Example](http://timmurphy.org/2014/04/26/using-fork-in-cc-a-minimum-working-example/)

Answer (score 4):

Adding a & in the end of the command should fork it and allow your program to continue, like this:

```
int main() {
system("java -jar /home/user/test/test.jar argument &");
cout << "The end" << endl;
return 0;}
```

I have something similar and it is working fine.

Comment: thank you very much, this works like a charm, thanx guys for really fast response!!